# Abbreviations for align

Tags: macros, align, amsmath

I know from the [Technical notes on the `amsmath` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.pdf) that it is not possible to introduce direct abbreviations like

```
\newcommand{\bal}{\begin{align}} % doesn't work
\newcommand{\eal}{\end{align}}   % doesn't work
```

or

```
\newcommand{\bal}{\align}    % doesn't work
\newcommand{\eal}{\endalign} % doesn't work
```

What is puzzling me is that

```
\newenvironment{foo}{\align}{\endalign}
```

*does* work, at least if one is well-behaved enough to diligently type `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}`, since `\foo...\endfoo` won't work either.

I'd really appreciate some help to shed some light on what is going on behind the scenes `:-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, `\begin{align}` executes `\align`, which in turn calls `\start@align`.

This macro records what's in `\@currenvir` and sets things up so that the environment's contents to be absorbed is whatever comes up to the first appearance of `\end{align}`.

In case you do

```
\newenvironment{foo}{\align}{\endalign}
```

the execution of `\begin{foo}` will set `\@currenvir` to `foo`, so `\start@align` will make TeX absorb everything up to `\end{foo}`, then executing `\endfoo` (in this case, it is just `\endalign`).

This explains why

```
\newenvironment{foo}{\begin{align}}{\end{align}} % WRONG!
```

doesn't work: when `\start@align` is executed, `\begin` has set `\@currenvir` to `align` and there will be no *explicit* `\end{align}` to be found.

The same strategy is used by `environ` when `\NewEnviron` is processed, so also environments defined with it must appear in the “macro form” if we want to define new environments in terms of them.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking: Does it mean that `\start@align` looks for the _string_ `\end{\@currenvir}` or something like that?

Comment: @campa Not for the string, but for the tokens `\end•{•f•o•o•}` (the bullets are just for separating tokens) where `foo` is the current value of `\@currenvir`.

Comment: Thx. I really need to give a closer look to `amsmath.sty`. Or maybe I'll just pop up into your office next time I'm in VR `;-)`

Comment: @campa I'm waiting for you!