# paragraph ended before align was complete

Tags: align

I got the above named error after changing an eqnarray envrmt to align envrmt.
I was wondering if align does not work with doc class scrartcl, but the mwe of other users also seem to work like that. Also the error can't be in the formula, as in a sample formula like below the same problem occurs. 
Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\eq}{\begin{equation}} %Shortcuts für num. Einzelformel
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\begin{align}} %Shortcuts für ausgerichtete num. Formelsysteme
\newcommand{\eeqs}{\end{align}}

\begin{document}    

\eqs
a&=b+c\\
de&=fg+hi
\eeqs

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/what-is-wrong-with-defining-bal-as-beginalign

Comment: As you have now learned, making short names for macros is not a good idea. Not only do they not always work, they also make the code harder to read.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314533/82917 for a detailed explanation as why this does not work.