# Abbreviate \begin{frame}

Tags: beamer, definition

I would like to abbreviate `\begin{frame} \end{frame}` environment of Beamer. For most Latex environments, I could do this using a basic `\def` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\be{\begin{enumerate}\item}
\def\ne{\item}
\def\ee{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\be One
\ne Two
\ne Three
\ee

\end{document}
```

This works and is much more compact than the full syntax. But if I try to do something similar for Beamer it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\be{\begin{frame}}
\def\ee{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\be A frame \ee
\be Another frame \ee

\end{document}
```

```
Runaway argument?
\let \AtEndDocument \@firstofone \@enddocumenthook \@checkend {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

Why wouldn't this work for the frame environment in particular?

Comment: Basically the `frame` environment collects stuff until it finds `\end{frame}`, and if you hide this under `\ee` it will never be found.

Comment: I strongly advise against this. Otherwise, you will find yourself in an isolated island and no one can understand your code, and a large gate for obscure errors gets opened. If you need more efficiency writing code, then most editors have shortcuts for inserting commands and complete environments by pressing two keys or something in milliseconds.

Comment: @campa Thanks, that answers my "why" question. The "how" question was answered by the linked question so I will close this one as duplicate.

Comment: There is a similar problem for `align`: [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314533/82917) describes the "why" more in detail in that case. The situation with `frame` is similar.