# `\newenvironment` throwing errors

Tags: macros, errors, environments

I defined an environment:

```
% Custom environment
% \begin{subeqns}[eq:label] 
%   ...
% \end{subeqns}
\newenvironment{subeqns}[1][]
    {
        \begin{subequations} \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{\label{#1}} 
            \begin{align}
    }
    {
            \end{align}
        \end{subequations}
    }
```

And use it in a document:

```
\begin{subeqns}
    hello &= 7 \\
        3 &= 4
\end{subeqns}
```

And it produces the desired output:

[image]

However, it's **throwing errors** in the LaTeX compile log:

```
  1 main.tex|51 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{align} on input line 49 ended by \end{subeqns}.
  3 main.tex|54 error| LaTeX Error: \begin{subequations} on input line 49 ended by \end{document}.
```

**How can I get rid of these errors?**

Comment: unrelated, but shouldn't the `\label` be placed *after* `\begin{subequations}` for correct referencing? Your custom env doesn't have its own counter, so it has to rely on `subequations`

Comment: @marquinho yes, thanks.

Comment: unrelated, too: Your comment signs are pure decorations. If you really want to get rid of spurious spaces, you have to put them immediately behind the last non-space character, e.g. `}%` instead of `} %`.

Comment: @gernot thanks, I didn't know that. I probably don't need them anyway.

Comment: the `align` environment does something to capture the environment contents, so it wouldn't work if the tokens "`\end{align}`" cannot be scanned. using `\NewDocumentEnvironment` with `b` works.

Comment: @plante if you post a working example I will try it.

Comment: @Myridium this is also explained in the [`xparse` documentation](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf), sec. 1.1 and 1.3 for the optional argument, sec. 1.6 for the specification `b` in an environment. (In recent LaTeX distributions, `xparse` is part of the kernel, so don't need to load it as a package)

Comment: I figured something using @plante's advice, thanks.

Comment: @Myridium Great! Remember that you can (some time soon) accept your own answer to mark the issue as solved, for future reference and for forum housekeeping :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to collect the whole environment with the `b` specifier of `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. While you can't hide `\begin{align}` in the start code of your custom environment, you *can* use the internal macro `\align` (shameless self-publicity: [Abbreviations for align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314530/82917)).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}% twocolumn only for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subeqns}[1][]{%
   \subequations
   \@ifnotempty{#1}{\label{#1}}%
   \align
  }{%
   \endalign
   \endsubequations
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text
\begin{subeqns}[parent]
a&=b \label{a}\\
a&=b \label{b}
\end{subeqns}
Text text text text text text text text text.
Eq.~\eqref{parent} consists of Eqs.~\eqref{a}
and \eqref{b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something I don't understand about TeX: how am I *supposed to know* that an environment like `subequations` or `align` is different from others? And how am I supposed to know that there exist commands `\subequations` and `\align` as workarounds? Please don't say *read the manual*; that's a luxury few can afford.

Comment: @Myridium Sorry, but if you don't want to read the manual there is nothing much to do. Don't misunderstand me: I absolutely understand your frustration! However, either you are a user which simply uses the provided tools, or you want to write your own code, and this presupposes some knowledge of the system's inner working. But as a general tip when you wrap an existing environment `foo` in a custom environment, using the inner macros `\foo` and `\endfoo` is always a good idea.

Comment: There is something distinctly different about TeX's learning curve though. I've programmed in several languages and been doing so for years. TeX is fundamentally *bad* in a way that's difficult to describe. I'm not a computer scientist so I don't know the high level concepts behind language design. But TeX is the only language that I haven't become competent in after years of use. Design patterns which work in one place do not work in another. Solutions are never watertight; there's always some exception which breaks them. It never ends. Other languages, I can be a power user and program tools

Answer (score 3):

Using plante's suggested command,

```
% Custom environment
% \begin{subeqns}[eq:label] 
%   ...
% \end{subeqns}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{subeqns}{o+b}
    { 
        \begin{subequations} \IfNoValueF{#1}{\label{#1}}
            \begin{align}
                #2
            \end{align}
        \end{subequations}
    } 
    {
    }
```

Input:

```
\begin{subeqns}[myEqn]
    hello &= 7 \\
    3 &= 4 \\
    \text{My eqref} &= \eqref{myEqn}
\end{subeqns}
```

Output:

[image]

Note: `\usepackage{xparse}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` needed.